# Why object of type sf::Text returns different getPosition().y and getLocalBounds().top?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to precisely set the position of sf::Text in SFML 2.4.1, but after I set the font, its location is improper.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    sf::Text text;
    text.setCharacterSize(24);
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("Font.ttf"); //without loading any font, everything's correct
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("A String");
    text.setPosition(0, 61);
    std::cout << text.getOrigin().y;
    std::cout << text.getPosition().y;
    std::cout << text.getGlobalBounds().top;
    std::cout << text.getLocalBounds().top;
    if (text.getLocalBounds().top != text.getPosition().y) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the origin, but it didn't help.

```
text.setOrigin(0, text.getGlobalBounds().height/2.f); //height is correct and it matches with what displays on the screen(draw code is unnecessary)
```

Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the first line is aligned vertically on the height of the tallest character (even if it's not in the string). This is to keep the top of the string steady even if you add higher characters on the first line. Thanks to [Laurent](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=5790.0).